# What exactly makes this logo a design failure such that viewers cannot decipher the company's name?

Tags: logo, critique, design-principles, readability

In a featured [Stack Overflow Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412334/self-promotion-in-images), there was a logo of a company, which looks like this:

[image: Company logo]

<sub>(The logo might be copyrighted. It is posted here for discussion purposes only.)</sub>

I failed to recognize the company name, which is

> dahua  (Zhejiang Dahua Technology Co., Ltd.)

One of the highly upvoted comments was

> Follow-up question: Is it still self-promotion if most users cannot decipher the company name? ;)

Why exactly is it so hard to decipher the company name here? Which design principles were missed? Which design principles work towards a different interpretation, specifically "alhua"?

Comment: So you mean that a undecipherable name is not a failure in it self? Anyway your body and question header has a different question

Comment: It's not a failure, it does perfectly well its job as a warning sign https://cybersecurityworldconference.com/2021/10/07/poc-exploit-for-2-flaws-in-dahua-cameras-leaked-online/

Comment: @joojaa: IMHO, the failure is that the company name cannot be diciphered. Do you see other failures? Sorry, if there are multiple and I didn't recognize that.

Comment: I could see D easily but I was not sure if I should read it as dahua or adhua. I think that's a problem.

Comment: Sidebar... thanks for showing me how to use a spoiler `:)`

Comment: I read "alhua" and interpreted the circle as some kind of messed-up @.

Comment: I also saw Alhua and never would guess that the red circle was part of a letter. Basically, you can change the shape *or* the colour of a letter, but never both at the same time, or it ceases to be a letter in the word. And not ever can you play with the left-to-right order of elements and expect anyone to make sense of it.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what Chinese people would say of our attempts to make a native Chinese text based business logo.

Comment: I don't think even Chinese writing employs any inherent back-and-forth for reading. It's still *one* single direction as far as I understand. I could, of course, be wrong `:)`

Comment: I suspect this logo is less faily in China than in the West. As speakers of languages with more complex phonotactics, we consider _adhua_ or _alhua_ (or perhaps even _ajhua_, depending on native language) to be equally likely alternatives, but to a Chinese speaker, these will not be possible alternatives at all, since they’re not possible sequences of sound in Chinese. _Lahua_ and _dahua_ are (_jiahua_ is as well, but not _jahua_), so I suspect Chinese people will be quicker to jump to the correct sequence of letters, at least, if not necessarily the correct identification of the d/l.

Comment: i read it as ajhua with a high degree of uncertainty, thinking maybe it's @jhua. far enough off that the only way i'd be able to google it was if there happens to be a number of others that are wondering what "ajhua" is.

Comment: Plot twist: the logo was specifically designed to be unreadable in a hard to understand and interesting way, so as to make it into the StackExchange hot questions, for purposes of self-promotion...

Comment: The failure here is a Chinese designer treating English like a pictographic language.  Chinese characters build on one another through composition - layering of ideas.  The physical layout of the language is different, so breaking left-to-right letter order would not be so instinctively destructive to meaning.  Chinese makes new words by "squishing" multiple root characters in and around each other to form a single new composite character.  Letters alone have no meaning in English, though, so composing them around each other like this is just nonsensical and confusing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## **Eye movement**

Regardless of whether a language employs left-to-right or right-to-left reading, in order for a word, any word, to be comprehended easily you **can't** ask the reader to "zig zag" mid-word.

While I would have **never** deciphered the actual name from this mark... once I know it's supposed to be "dahua", it's clear the designer is asking the user to read d.. *back up*, then read a... then skip the pseudo-J/l... and read "hua".

If one removes color from the mark, the eye movement is still a "zig zag" if the mark (name) is to be read correctly. That zig zag is **not normal behavior for readers**. The designer is asking the viewer to essentially *ignore* all they have ever learned about reading a word.

[image]

- Given color breaks, the flair of the d is pushed as a possibly *separate* and unrelated element, leaving that red vertical to be interpreted as a J or l (as @Tetsujin mentions in his answer). Without color, there's **really** a strong sense that it's a J or l.
- There is greater letter spacing around that first `a` - which is more apparent once color is removed. This promotes the idea that the a is somewhat separate, or the start of the word.
- Because the heavy, vertical, stroke of the d falls **after** the a, it promotes the perception that, even in the unlikely event the d is read as a d, it falls *after* the a.

The eye **must** perform hurdles if the company name is to be deciphered from this mark. The eye is all over the place, making for a bad mark.

*Good* marks have intentional, *fluid*, motion which *lead* the eye rather than asking the eye to do summersaults.

Anyway I see it, I read either "aJhua", "adhua", or "alhua".

Comment: Yup. I'd implied that - but you've stated it clearly. Same in photography or painting - lead the eye, don't make it jump all over the place.

Comment: Single-colour seems to open up Oalhua.

Comment: I thought it was "a-hua". The "d" just didn't register as a letter at all.

Answer (score 24):

I somewhat disagree with the existing answers and think the fundamental problems are these:

- The *d* has lost too many properties fundamental to a *d* and the Latin alphabet in general:

  - The bowl is too big and too thin in comparison to the stem.
    Usually, strokes going in the same direction should have the same width.
  - The bowl goes below the baseline – which is established by the rest of the text as well as the stem sloping away on that level.
  - The opening is at an odd place, if not a wrong one: You would never leave a gap there when writing such a letter by hand, but instead put it at the upper collision of bowl and stems.

  This becomes more apparent if we look at the *d* in isolation:

  [image: isolated d]

  This does not look like a Latin letter at all, but rather like a snail crawling uphill.
  If a letter, this is rather an *a* or a *J* with an extreme swash.
  It becomes better if embedded in the logo, but I still think this will most likely be read as *Jahua:*

  [image: Jahua]
- By form and spacing, the stem of the *d* integrates into the rest of the text like a letter. Except for the leftwards bend at the bottom and a bit of extra space on the left, it is exactly like you would expect an *l* at this position to look like.

To somewhat illustrate this, consider the following alternatives that only fix the two issues above:

[image: same concept as logo with unmodified letters]

Mind that these are still far from good, but at least you have a decent chance of decyphering them as intended: It’s either *dahua* or *adhua* and the colour or special position of the *d* make it clear which one is the intended reading. In the first case, you will first read *dhua,* which probably doesn’t fit your expected orthographic conventions and on a second glance, you will see the *a* to correct it. In the second case, you first read *ahua,* at a second glance you will note the *d,* and at third thought you will know where to place it.

Of course, it’s still a problem that you need those second glances and some mental work.
It might somewhat help, if a capital *d* were used, but it probably wouldn’t suffice.

Comment: I think you'd still end up with `adhua` & perhaps think they were an advertising company. `dah` doesn't ring to an English ear as the first part of a word, so it's the least likely conclusion.

Comment: I disagree with the first point: while true that it looks _less like_ a regular d, the real problem is the positioning with the "a" inside. If it would be positioned to the left of the first "a" it would have a higher chance of being read as `dahua`.

Comment: @Luciano: Well, we would have to make a survey with uninitiated people to decide this, but see my edit.

Comment: True, maybe _I think I can_ see it because I now know what to look for. Your edit makes the case for an embelished J more clear.

Comment: I'd still read the second example as "adhua", given that there is much more space between the "a" and "h" than between other letters.  If the "d" were moved slightly to the left, and the "a" moved to match the spacing of the other letters (thus hanging out from the right edge of the "d") that would improve things enormously.

Comment: I agree that the change in thickness of the different part of the “d” is a huge aspect in what leads to the belief of separate glyphs.

Comment: Of your three alternate forms (the edited original and the two plain-text ones), I still read the first as _ahua_ with a graphic squiggle (as I do the original) – but interestingly, I read the second as _dahua_ and the third as _adhua_. I’m guessing the identical x-height/font size is what gives my brain the clue as to which letter should come first.

Comment: Still it's probably a bad idea to design logos that read like C typedefs.

Answer (score 12):

The main aspect of this logo that confused me is the similarity of the  first symbol to an at sign. For example, look at the logo compared to the primary image on the Wikipedia page for an at sign:

[image: standard at sign]
vs
[image: company logo mentioned in the original post]

This similarity led me to consider the names Athua, Atlhua, and Alhua. However, the name Dahua never crossed my mind.

Additionally, if I had previously been informed that the red letter is a "d," I still would have gotten it wrong and called the company Adhua due to the very prominent leading letter "a."

Answer (score 11):

Personally, I feel the major fail is not fully comprehending the western left to right reading bias.
Left to right reading is a stronger influence than 'read the red letter first, then the black ones'.

So, reading left to right you get…
an `a` in a circle, followed by a red `j`, then `hua`.

Breaking the circle where `technology` is written reinforces the `j` over `l` interpretation & makes the red look even less like a `d`.

Conclusion - the logo says `ajhua`
If I were asked to extrapolate further, given my interpretation of an emphasised `a` followed by an emphasised `j`, I may even guess the company name was `A. Jhua` & not a single word.

Had I not revealed the spoiler, there is not a chance I would have ever arrived at `dahua`.

Comment: Everything I would have stated - Only done probably more elegantly and succinctly. `:)`

Comment: Yeah, I was going to write the same. Looks like aJhua to me as well.

Comment: To add another one: My first guess was adhua...

Comment: I never got the `d` at all. Prompted by the rest of the question, I spent some time actually trying to decide what it was intended to be, rather than jumping straight into the spoiler. Never found a `d`.

Comment: You may want to point out the the bow would just be interpretted as a "bad" swash of somekind.

Comment: Am I the only one who got ahua?

Comment: @Joshua Nope, me too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I thought it was a "alhua" with a particularly cursive flourish.